# Webpack file loade not displaying icon images on the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Well since my webpack expercise is not so good I having problem getting some icons to display on the browser. My setup looks like this on webpack:

```html
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'url?limit=100000?name=fonts/[name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'url?limit=100000',
      },
```

The icons I have are located here:

[image]